# Re-use C# SQLParameters in loop?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I create a command (stord proc) and add two parameters. I would then like to iterate through an array and simply re-assign the two parameters on each loop and execute the query. I originally used `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name,value)` INSIDE the loop, which suggests my number of parameters is increasing by 2 every loop iteration (it worked- but still, not good design). However, I would like to do this the proper way.

I also tried clearing the parameter list at the end of each loop iteration and re-adding the parameters in the loop- but this didnt work at all. Nothing got insertd in to the database

How do I assign/create the two parameters to the command outside of the loop and then inside the loop assign new values to the two parameters and execute?

```cs
//Set command text

//Create both parameters

//loop

  // assign parameter 1
  // assign parameter 2

  // execute command

//end loop
```

Comment: real code. real answers.

Comment: If I knew the real code for assigning the parameters I wouldn't be asking....

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the index of the parameters to reassign values.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl where id = @id AND otherID = @other");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@other", SqlDbType.Int);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
   cmd.Parameters["@other"].Value = i * 10;

   cmd.Execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//Set command text

//Create both parameters
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);

//loop

// assign parameter 1
// assign parameter 2
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerIDs[i];
command.Parameters["@Age"].Value = customerAges[i];


// execute command

//end loop
```